# Unable to resolve "Error 3061. Too few parameters. Expected 1"

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have these lines in VBA

```
strTOP = "SELECT * FROM CM_qryBOM WHERE BOM_Address Like '*" & Me.Part_No & "'"
Set rsTOP = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTOP, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Which results in the following SQL statement that I verified in the Immediate window.

```
SELECT * FROM CM_qryBOM WHERE BOM_Address Like '*601541-19'
```

The query does not execute and throws error code 3061 when running from VBA. However, when I copy and paste the same query into Query Design SQL view it runs just fine.

Never encountered this before and not sure how to fix. Tried bracketing the [table name] and [field name] but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual suspect, in this case, is the query you're selecting from (CM_qryBOM).

It likely is using form or report values as parameters (or querying off other queries that do). Those aren't available when using `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`.

You can manually set them by using a querydef and parameters, or you can construct a query that only queries tables, not other queries, to be safe.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Thank you.